# Dynamically create a grid with n columns of equal width

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

**With SCSS, how can I dynamically create a `grid` that has *n* columns of *equal* width?**

Current approach:

```
// grid setup
$columns: 4;
$columnGap: 20px;
$rowGap: 30px;

// grid
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat( $columns, auto );
grid-template-rows: auto;
grid-column-gap: $columnGap;
grid-row-gap: $rowGap;
```

The problem with this is that `auto` does not actually produce columns of the *same* width. Instead, some columns may be wider or narrower depending on their content.

What I would like is for all columns to have the exact same width.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grid-template-columns: repeat( $columns, 1fr)` - see a demo below in *vanilla CSS* to show that it works:

```css
:root {
  --columns: 4;
  --columnGap: 20px;
  --rowGap: 30px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-column-gap: var(--columnGap);
  grid-row-gap: var(--rowGap);
}

.grid>div {
  background: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div>Some </div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>Some </div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: TLDR: Replace `auto` with `1fr`.